Good book on procrastination
I wanted to read about what psychologists have found out about procrastination over decades, and what are the currently most widely accepted theories, findings etc. regarding the reasons, symptoms, remedy and other topics related to procrastination. Is there any book or other resource which gives a comprehensive overview of the topic?
When I search for books on procrastination online, I find it hard to distinguish which are trustable scholarly resources and which are not scientific/ evidence backed. Therefore, I thought it would be appropriate to ask here. I am not only interested in remedies, but also in understanding more about it. I do not mind it being technical.

Which books make you find it hard to distinguish its credibility? If you don't mind reading academic article, you can search the topic on Google Scholars
